# what does the | symbol do in python

Tags: python

I'm wondering what | does in python. I thought it chose the greater value but it seems I was wrong because this is what I tried at first.

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 5
>>> a | b
10
```

Then I tried this:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = -1
>>> a | b
-1
```

I tried with some other negative numbers and it continued to return -1 so it's not choosing the least value either as far as I know so what is it doing?

Comment: [See the FAQ.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does a bitwise "or".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

It is also in C, C++, Java, Javascript, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe character is a `bitwise or` operator. Refer to the [documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

If you want to choose the greater value, use the `max` builtin:

```
>>> max(1, 2)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone is making jokes here :P

`|` operator is a "bitwise or" operator. In your example:

`10 | 5` means (in bits):

```
  1010
| 0101
= 1111
```

Which gives:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 5
>>> a | 5
15
```

(in my Python2.7 :P)